# AX 2012 - ListPage FactBox Part does not refresh on Sub Datasources selection change

Tags: refresh, datasource, dynamics-ax-2012, axapta

my issue is on the ReqTransPOListPage, I added a FactBox Part related by ItemId

When the user navigates in the Grid records
- If the selected field on grid is one of the main DS ReqPO then the FactBox get refreshed!
- But if the selected field on the grid is a field of any sub DataSource of Query, then PCDataSourceEventNotify.onRefresh() is not triggered and neither my FactBox.

I can't even force refresh in ReqTrans_DS.active() since it's a ListPage based on AOT Query and datasource methods cannot be overriden.

some ideas?