# How to refresh Factbox

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, x++, dynamics-ax-2012-r2, dynamics-ax-2012-r3

I have a form, when i click on my button.It adds to my table A (what my factbox shows)is it possible to refresh the factbox with X++ code? I can't figure out how to refresh my infopart or query which factbox uses.

Comment: Related: [AX 2012 - ListPage FactBox Part does not refresh on Sub Datasources selection change](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22482153/ax-2012-listpage-factbox-part-does-not-refresh-on-sub-datasources-selection-ch)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For an infopart you can call an update of the data source of the infopart's form run:

```csharp
void clicked()
{
    PartList       partList;
    int            i;
    FormRun        infoPartFormRun;
    FormDataSource infoPartDataSource;

    super();

    partList = new PartList(element);
    for (i = 1; i <= partList.partCount(); i++)
    {
        infoPartFormRun = partList.getPartById(i);
        if (infoPartFormRun.name() == identifierStr(MyInfoPart))
        {
            infoPartDataSource = infoPartFormRun.dataSource();
            if (infoPartDataSource)
            {
                infoPartDataSource.research();   
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I added the check for the `infoPartDataSource` because I first tested this with a cue group fact box, which does not have a data source (or at least I could not figure out how to get the data source of one of the cues in the cue group and since you asked for an infopart fact box, I did not investigate further).

**Update**: The issue seems to be popular at the moment, Martin Dráb also wrote in his blog about it: [Refreshing form parts](http://dev.goshoom.net/en/2015/11/refreshing-form-parts/)